# How to avoid duplication in terraform when having multiple services in ECS which differ only in the command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

We create ECS services in Terraform by defining a template_file which populates a task definition JSON template with all needed variables. Then a `aws_ecs_task_definition` is created with the rendered template_file. With this task definition the `aws_ecs_service` is created:

```
data "template_file" "web" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/tasks/web.json")}"

  vars {
    ...
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "web" {
  container_definitions    = "${data.template_file.web.rendered}"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  ...
}

data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "web" {
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.family}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "web" {
  name            = "web"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.web.revision}")}"
  ...
}
```

There are additional services with task definitions nearly identical to the first one, only having small differences like another command (for example for starting sidekiq instead of the web app).

Is there any other way of doing this other than duplicating everything (the JSON template, `template_file` with all defined variables, `aws_ecs_task_definition` and `aws_ecs_service`)?

Comment: You could probably solve this with an array or map iterated over for each resource with `count.index`, but I am speculating given the example. This also might be easier in 0.12 where variable blocks are possible (I forget specifics around that; I saw it on a Github issue somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html) are the main way to solve this in Terraform.

If you move your existing code into a single folder you can then define variables that allow you to customise that module such as the command to be passed to your ECS service.

So in your case you might have something like this:

#### modules/foo-service/main.tf

```
data "template_file" "web" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/tasks/web.json")}"

  vars {
    # ...
    command = "${var.command}"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "web" {
  container_definitions    = "${data.template_file.web.rendered}"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  # ...
}

data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "web" {
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.family}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "web" {
  name            = "web"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.web.revision}")}"
  # ...
}
```

#### modules/foo-service/variables.tf

```
variable "command" {}
```

#### staging/main.tf

```
module "foo_service_web" {
  source  = "../modules/foo-service"
  command = "bundle exec server"
}

module "foo_service_sidekiq" {
  source  = "../modules/foo-service"
  command = "bundle exec sidekiq"
}
```

Comment: this would still require passing all the non changing variables to both module blocks, right? This is what I am most concerned about as it encapsulates most of the complexity. I really like your idea with the array/map though, this could be used to first define the unchanging variables and then merge them with the changing variables to have a DRY definition. I will try it out and let you know!

Comment: If they're the same for both then don't set them as variables to the module and instead just hardcode things or set them as default variables or locals. Ideally your module should only expose variables for things where you actually need them to change (eg environment specific things or in your case the command).

Comment: @induktiv I've rejected the edit you suggested because none of what you added was relevant to the question as you had omitted the usage of a load balancer that would be different between them. If you wanted to ask a more detailed question based on this one (and probably linking back to this) then your extra edit would potentially be a good self answer. I would point out though that not everything needs to be in the module so if you have an app server container that needs a load balancer then the load balancer could live outside of the module while the main ECS service is still in the module.

Comment: That would allow you to share the useful parts and not have to worry about conditional logic around whether a resource should be included in a much cleaner way IMO. I personally have modules for ECS tasks (task definitions and optional IAM task roles and policies) and then ECS service and ECS web service modules that differ based on whether they are accessed via a load balancer or not.

Comment: I am happy to leave out the comments about the 0.12 Terraform feature. I think the merge part of the edit is very relevant to the question as it removes the duplication for all but the most simple cases of just having one variable. My question contains the phrase "only having small differences like another command" so having a solution for managing more than one variable would be helpful for answering the question. Should I take another go at an edit and also update the title of the question to not contradict the body in this specific point?

Comment: I think the existing answer successfully answers the existing question. If you then encountered something extra that was hard to do with the existing answer with some changes that don't exist in the question as is and you think it would be useful for others then consider asking another more complete question and self answering.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted answer to show how to also remove the duplication caused by the defined variables in the `template_file` vars block (which do not change and thus would have to be duplicated between invocations of the module). It is also not a solution to just inline these variables or use defaults because they still will change between projects, just not within services of the same project. We can use local variables for setting the defaults and overriding defaults with the merge function:

#### main.tf

```
locals {
  task_variables = {
    image = "..."
    # lots of other variables
    command = "[\"nginx\", \"-g\", \"daemon off; error_log /dev/stdout info;\"]"
  }
}

# first invocation of the module, overriding the command
module "sidekiq" {
  source = "ecs_service"
  ...
  task_variables = "${merge(
    local.task_variables,
    map(
      "command", "[\"bash\", \"-c\", \"exec bundle exec sidekiq\"]",
    )
  )}"
}

# second invocation of the module, no overrides
module "web" {
  source = "ecs_service"
  task_variables = "${local.task_variables}"
}
```

#### Module ecs_service

```
variable "task_variables" {
  type = "map"
}

data "template_file" "web_task" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/tasks/task_definition.json")}"

  vars = "${var.task_variables}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "web" {
  container_definitions    = "${data.template_file.web_task.rendered}"
  ...
}

data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "web" {
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.family}"
  ...
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "web" {
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.web.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.web.revision}")}"
  ...
}
```